# How can I implement an autosearch TextBox, with short delay?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, search

I have a `GridView` that my users will need to filter based off of criteria entered into multiple filter text fields.

The easiest approach for this issue is to create the needed `TextBox` controls and once a user is finished, that can click a Search button to execute the search.

However, what I would prefer is that as my users are typing, the application will call an update on the `GridView` controls `UpdatePanel` which will update the grid as they type.

I can do this on text change events but there is on major caveat that will need for my scenario-- I need the actual search to execute after a slight pause after the last key press.

My reasoning should be obvious.  If a user enters a 20-30 character search string (which is quite possible) I don't want the page to make 20-30 update request.  Instead, once a user has paused for, say 500 millisecond, I want to execute the update.

Is there a straight-forward approach to doing this?

Currently I'm using JQuery and Bootstrap.  I'd prefer that any answer either only these libraries OR some other very light-weight JS tool.  Also, this is not an auto-complete question.  I don't need for the `TextBox` to include text post-appended, nor do I want a drop-down to appear under my `TextBox` suggesting content.  I want to update the data that is being displayed, dynamically, as a user searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple Javascript timeout which clears on every keyup of your input field.

```js
$(function() {

  var timeout;

  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#result").text('You searched for ' + $("#search").val());
    }, 500);

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [debounce library](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce). You just wrap your handler with `$.debounce` and the desired delay as an argument.

```js
$("#text").on("keyup", $.debounce(250, function() {
   $("#log").append($("<li/>").text(this.value));
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/master/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js"></script>
Text: <input id="text"/>
<ul id="log"></ul>
```